# 「～にわたって」の使い方を説明してくれる方がいますか？

Tags: grammar, usage

「～にわたって」を使う問題をやってみましたがなぜかほとんど間違えました。なぜ間違えたのか説明してくれませんか？教科書の写真（黄色い丸は僕が選んだ選択肢です）
[image]

Comment: 正しい解答は教科書で書いてありますか？それも投稿できれば役に立てるかもしれません。

Comment: それと、「にわたって」は主に「広い範囲」と「長い間」を表す言葉と使われているので、「うちの庭にわたって」とかは言いません。

Comment: 念のためですが、正解は上から c, c, b, a ですか？（間違ってたら日本語勉強し直します）

Answer (score 2):

正しい答えは

1. c
2. c
3. b
4. a

で合っていますでしょうか？

## 「にわたって」

- ある「期間」の中で「ずっと」続いているもの
- ある「範囲」の中で「まんべんなく」あるもの

## 問題解説

1. 「5月」と「5月の連休」は、期間ではなく、特定の日にち
2. 「うちの庭」と「駅前」は、範囲ではなく、特定の場所
   だから間違いです。
   しかし、「5月」のことを「5月1日から31日まで」だと考えれば期間ですよね？「うちの庭」も「門から扉まで」だと思えば範囲になりますし、そこで混乱が起きるかと思います。

なので「期間」、または「範囲」を表現する言葉とセットになっていることを確認した方が分かりやすいかと思います。
具体的にいうと「〇〇間」、「全体」、「全国」などです。
実際に「5月1日から31日にわたって」、「駅前全体にわたって」なら間違いではないです。

3. 「富士山が一番高い」と「四つの大きな島がある」は、特定の場所（まんべんではない）
4. 「魚屋を開いた」と「魚屋を閉じた」は、完了している動作（続いていない）
   を表しているので間違いです。